# ¿Como hago yo para guardar los valores de la clasificación de huevos y poder calcular cuantas bandejas tengo?

Tags: python, funciones, variables

En el ejercicio se me pide clasificar cierto numero de huevos que se me da en una lista, luego se eso se me pide calcular, cuantas bandejas de huevos obtengo según la clasificación, por ultimo se me pide dar el resultado como una biblioteca.

Mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para llevar esos valores de una función a la otra función, y como hago para hacer esa biblioteca.

lo he intentado hacer por varios lados pero aun no me resultado.

```py
mi_lista = [62.42148528616925, 81.38485285533801, 6.351343245021135, 33.92000692227505, 78.60898225792742, 1.9555364491762317, 52.137158224456485, 48.36409297422547, 4.665400902129657, 27.98264067496894, 32.20920610835459, 76.10176844347531, 86.27440365475539, 94.29168151284377, 36.972236559301585, 61.05997917507268, 0.2230599887911522, 67.48874617255551, 6.565212834490286, 10.870002918724264, 76.21202524287186, 42.30960703792308, 10.267404039327477, 68.09445053955268, 92.92920362121251, 78.84148980390123, 85.85478530913802, 30.216683993776105, 43.53409272010531, 18.96988315524292,42.73165457233904, 62.34349893758201]

def clasificacion_huevos(mi_lista):
  
  huevos_AAA = 0
  huevos_AA = 0
  huevos_A = 0
  huevos_BC = 0
    
  for huevo in mi_lista:      
    if huevo >= 55 and huevo < 60:
      huevos_A += 1
      print(f'A: {huevos_A}')
    elif huevo >= 60 and huevo < 69:
      huevos_AA += 1
      print(f'AA: {huevos_AA}')
    elif huevo >= 69:
      huevos_AAA += 1
      print(f'AAA: {huevos_AAA}')
    elif huevo < 53:
      huevos_BC += 1
      print(f'BC: {huevos_BC}')
  return clasificacion_huevos
print(clasificacion_huevos(mi_lista))

def calcular_cajas(huevos_A, huevos_AA, huevos_AAA, huevos_BC):

  if huevos_A / 30 >= 1:
    huevosA = huevos_A / 30
    A = math.floor(huevosA)
    print(f'bandeja_A: {A}')
  else:
    A = 0
    print(f'bandeja_A: {A}')

  if huevos_AA /24 >= 1:
    huevosAA = huevos_AA / 24
    AA = math.floor(huevosAA)
    print(f'bandejas_AA: {AA}')
  else:
    AA = 0
    print(f'bandejas_AA: {AA}')

  if huevos_AAA /12 >= 1:
    huevosAAA = huevos_AAA / 12
    AAA = math.floor(huevosAAA)
    print(f'bandejas_AAA: {AAA}')
  else:
    AAA = 0
    print(f'bandejas_AAA: {AAA}')

  if huevos_BC / 30 >= 1:
    huevosBC = huevos_BC / 30
    BC = math.floor(huevosBC)
    print(f'bandejas_BC: {BC}')
  else:
    BC = 0
    print(f'bandejas_BC: {BC}')
    
print(calcular_cajas(huevos_A, huevos_AA, huevos_AAA, huevos_BC))
  result = [{'tipo_huevo': 'AAA', 'numero_huevos': huevos_AAA, 'numero_bandejas': AAA}
            {'tipo_huevo': 'AA', 'numero_huevos': huevos_AA, 'numero_bandejas': AA}
            {'tipo_huevo': 'A', 'numero_huevos': huevos_A, 'numero_bandejas': A}
            {'tipo_huevo': 'BC', 'numero_huevos': huevos_BC, 'numero_bandejas': BC}]
  return result
```

Comment: Bienvenid@ a SO, el código va como texto, por favor [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/456882/edit) tu pregunta

Comment: ¿Podrías poner tu código en forma de texto por favor? Puedes hacerlo editando la pregunta (el botón editar se encuentra abajo de la pregunta y las etiquetas) 
y pegando el código en la pregunta. Para darle formato, puedes seleccionar todo el código y presionar las {} que están arriba de la caja de texto.
En este link se explica la importancia de NO poner capturas de código en una pregunta: 
[Un fragmento de código vale más que mil imagenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2990/un-fragmento-de-c%C3%B3digo-vale-m%C3%A1s-que-mil-im%C3%A1genes-c%C3%B3mo-sensibilizar-a-los-usu)

Comment: @DanteS. me encanto la frase :)

Comment: listo compañeros.

Comment: @NaoG. Listo :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok para hacer lo que pides creo que seria mas fácil guardar en una lista donde la clave sea el tipo de huevo y su valor sea la lista de huevo, he optado por crear una lista que contenga el numero de huevo, esto lo puedes remplazar solo por la cantidad.

```py
def clasificacion_huevos(mi_lista):
  #creamos las listas donde se almacenara cada tipo de huevo
  huevos_AAA = []
  huevos_AA = []
  huevos_A = []
  huevos_BC = []

  #recorremos la lista y si cumple alguna condición agregamos a la lista correspondiente
  for huevo in mi_lista:      
    if huevo >= 55 and huevo < 60:
      huevos_A.append(huevo)
    elif huevo >= 60 and huevo < 69:
      huevos_AA.append(huevo)
    elif huevo >= 69:
      huevos_AAA.append(huevo)
    
    elif huevo < 53:
      huevos_BC.append(huevo)

  #finalmente creamos un diccionario donde se almacenará las listas
  clasificacion_huevos = {"huevos_AAA":huevos_AAA,"huevos_AA":huevos_AA,"huevos_A":huevos_A,"huevos_BC":huevos_BC}
  return clasificacion_huevos
```

Muy bien esto hace muy fácil el proceso de contar y obtener el número de cajas es fácil, como tu divides según el tipo de huevo, vamos a hacer un diccionario que contenga esos valores.

```py
def calcular_cajas(lista_huevos):
    #creamos el diccionario
    cajas = {"huevos_A":30,"huevos_AA":24,"huevos_AAA":12,"huevos_BC":30}
```

Luego solo tenemos que iterar

```
    for tipo in lista_huevos.keys():#iteramos sobre las keys
        cant_huevos = len(lista_huevos[tipo]) #obtenemos el numero de huevos
        # print(cant_huevos)
        if cant_huevos/cajas[tipo] >=1:#dividemos segun su tipo
            print(f"bandeja de {tipo}: {cant_huevos}") #imprimimos
        else:
            print(f"bandeja de {tipo}: 0")#imprimimos
```

**Ejecutamos**

```py
lista = clasificacion_huevos(mi_lista)
print(lista)

calcular_cajas(lista)
```

Como dije antes, en la función `clasificacion_huevos` puedes almacenar solo el numero de huevos y así te ahorras una linea de código en la otra función, lo almacene como listas por que si es una tarea, tal vez luego te pidan obtener esa lista, Además esa es una correcta clasificación.

Comment: Gracias, Christian el único problema es cuando corro el proceso no me imprime nada

Comment: Ha pues no puse ningun `print()`

Comment: @NaoG. añadí el código para que puedas ejecutarlo