# ¿Cómo solucionar un error al retornar?

Tags: python

hola amigos debo solucionar un problema que llevo resolviendo hace poco, sin embargo no me da la respuesta deseada este es código:

```
import math 
    
def clasificacion_huevos(huevos):
   contador1=0
   contador2 = 0
   contador3 = 0
   contador4 = 0
   contador5 = 0
   division1 = 0
   division2 = 0
   division3 = 0
   division4 = 0
   division5 = 0
   for i in huevos:
       if 53<=i<60:
            contador1 += 1
            division1 = contador1/30
   for x in huevos:
       if 60<=x<67:
            contador2 += 1
            division2 = contador2/24
   for y in huevos:
       if y>=67:
            contador3 += 1
            division3 = contador3/12
   for w in huevos:
       if 46<=w<53:
            contador4 += 1
            division4 = contador4/30
   for z in huevos:
       if z<46:
            contador5 += 1
            division5 = contador5/50
   return [{'tipo_huevos': 'A', 'numero_huevos': contador1, 'numero_bandejas':math.ceil(division1)},{'tipo_huevos': 'AA', 'numero_huevos': contador2, 'numero_bandejas': math.ceil(division2)}, {'tipo_huevos': 'AAA', 'numero_huevos': contador3, 'numero_bandejas': math.ceil(division3)},{'tipo_huevos': 'B', 'numero_huevos': contador4, 'numero_bandejas': math.ceil(division4)},{'tipo_huevos': 'C', 'numero_huevos': contador5, 'numero_bandejas': math.ceil(division5)}]

print(clasificacion_huevos([]))

def calcular_bandejas(bandejas):
    division1 = 0 
    division2 = 0
    division3 = 0
    division4 = 0
    division5 = 0
    division1 = bandejas[0]["numero_huevos"]/30
    division2 = bandejas[1]["numero_huevos"]/24
    division3 = bandejas[2]["numero_huevos"]/12
    division4 = bandejas[3]["numero_huevos"]/30
    division5 = bandejas[4]["numero_huevos"]/50
    
    return [{"tipo_huevos": "A", "numero_huevos": bandejas[0]["numero_huevos"], "numero_bandejas":math.ceil(division1)},{"tipo_huevos": "AA", "numero_huevos": bandejas[1]["numero_huevos"], "numero_bandejas":math.ceil(division2)},{"tipo_huevos": "AAA", "numero_huevos": bandejas[2]["numero_huevos"], "numero_bandejas":math.ceil(division3)},{"tipo_huevos": "B", "numero_huevos": bandejas[3]["numero_huevos"], "numero_bandejas":math.ceil(division4)},{"tipo_huevos": "C", "numero_huevos": bandejas[4]["numero_huevos"], "numero_bandejas":math.ceil(division5)}]
    
print(calcular_bandejas([{}]))
```

cuando coloco el primer `print()` es decir este `print(clasificacion_huevos([]))` siempre me da la respuesta adecuada que es

```
[{'tipo_huevos': 'A', 'numero_huevos': 0, 'numero_bandejas': 0},
{'tipo_huevos': 'AA', 'numero_huevos': 0, 'numero_bandejas': 0},
{'tipo_huevos': 'AAA', 'numero_huevos': 0, 'numero_bandejas': 0},
{'tipo_huevos': 'B', 'numero_huevos': 0, 'numero_bandejas': 0},
{'tipo_huevos': 'C', 'numero_huevos': 0, 'numero_bandejas': 0}]
```

Pero con la segunda función ósea la de calcular bandejas cuando pongo este `print()` vacío  `print(calcular_bandejas([{}]))`
siempre me da un error como este

```
division1 = bandejas[0]["numero_huevos"]/30

KeyError: 'numero_huevos'
```

Cuando debería ser igual a arriba es decir devolver el diccionario vacio si es que no hay argumentos pero que no se mezcle con lo clasificacion_huevos, ya que el objetivo es que el codigo cuando se llame la función calcular_bandejas solo me entrege eso directamente no las dos juntas:

```
[{'tipo_huevos': 'A', 'numero_huevos': 0, 'numero_bandejas': 0},
{'tipo_huevos': 'AA', 'numero_huevos': 0, 'numero_bandejas': 0}, 
{'tipo_huevos': 'AAA', 'numero_huevos': 0, 'numero_bandejas': 0},
{'tipo_huevos': 'B', 'numero_huevos': 0, 'numero_bandejas': 0},
{'tipo_huevos': 'C', 'numero_huevos': 0, 'numero_bandejas': 0}]
```

ya por ejemplo si le pongo argumentos a calcular_bandejas seria asi:

```
    
print(calcular_bandejas([{'tipo_huevos': 'A', 'numero_huevos': 250},
            {'tipo_huevos': 'AA', 'numero_huevos': 354},
            {'tipo_huevos': 'AAA', 'numero_huevos': 289},
            {'tipo_huevos': 'B', 'numero_huevos': 344},
            {'tipo_huevos': 'C', 'numero_huevos': 691}]))
```

y la respuesta deseada seria:

```
[{'tipo_huevos': 'A', 'numero_huevos': 250, 'numero_bandejas': 9}, 
{'tipo_huevos': 'AA', 'numero_huevos': 354, 'numero_bandejas': 15}, {'tipo_huevos': 'AAA', 'numero_huevos': 289, 'numero_bandejas': 25}, {'tipo_huevos': 'B', 'numero_huevos': 344, 'numero_bandejas': 12}, {'tipo_huevos': 'C', 'numero_huevos': 691, 'numero_bandejas': 14}]
```

y como pueden ver esta salida no tiene agregado clasificacion_huevos aunque arriba este: print(calcular_bandejas([{}])), sino que puntualmente solo entrega lo que hace la función calcular_bandejas

este es el codigo completo

```
import math 
    
def clasificacion_huevos(huevos):
   contador1=0
   contador2 = 0
   contador3 = 0
   contador4 = 0
   contador5 = 0
   division1 = 0
   division2 = 0
   division3 = 0
   division4 = 0
   division5 = 0
   for i in huevos:
       if 53<=i<60:
            contador1 += 1
            division1 = contador1/30
   for x in huevos:
       if 60<=x<67:
            contador2 += 1
            division2 = contador2/24
   for y in huevos:
       if y>=67:
            contador3 += 1
            division3 = contador3/12
   for w in huevos:
       if 46<=w<53:
            contador4 += 1
            division4 = contador4/30
   for z in huevos:
       if z<46:
            contador5 += 1
            division5 = contador5/50
   return [{'tipo_huevos': 'A', 'numero_huevos': contador1, 'numero_bandejas':math.ceil(division1)},{'tipo_huevos': 'AA', 'numero_huevos': contador2, 'numero_bandejas': math.ceil(division2)}, {'tipo_huevos': 'AAA', 'numero_huevos': contador3, 'numero_bandejas': math.ceil(division3)},{'tipo_huevos': 'B', 'numero_huevos': contador4, 'numero_bandejas': math.ceil(division4)},{'tipo_huevos': 'C', 'numero_huevos': contador5, 'numero_bandejas': math.ceil(division5)}]

print(clasificacion_huevos([]))

def calcular_bandejas(bandejas):
    division1 = 0 
    division2 = 0
    division3 = 0
    division4 = 0
    division5 = 0
    division1 = bandejas[0]["numero_huevos"]/30
    division2 = bandejas[1]["numero_huevos"]/24
    division3 = bandejas[2]["numero_huevos"]/12
    division4 = bandejas[3]["numero_huevos"]/30
    division5 = bandejas[4]["numero_huevos"]/50
    
    return [{"tipo_huevos": "A", "numero_huevos": bandejas[0]["numero_huevos"], "numero_bandejas":math.ceil(division1)},{"tipo_huevos": "AA", "numero_huevos": bandejas[1]["numero_huevos"], "numero_bandejas":math.ceil(division2)},{"tipo_huevos": "AAA", "numero_huevos": bandejas[2]["numero_huevos"], "numero_bandejas":math.ceil(division3)},{"tipo_huevos": "B", "numero_huevos": bandejas[3]["numero_huevos"], "numero_bandejas":math.ceil(division4)},{"tipo_huevos": "C", "numero_huevos": bandejas[4]["numero_huevos"], "numero_bandejas":math.ceil(division5)}]
    
print(calcular_bandejas([{'tipo_huevos': 'A', 'numero_huevos': 250}, {'tipo_huevos': 'AA', 'numero_huevos': 354}, {'tipo_huevos': 'AAA', 'numero_huevos': 289},{'tipo_huevos': 'B', 'numero_huevos': 344},{'tipo_huevos': 'C', 'numero_huevos': 691}]))
```

Comment: te codigo se puede mejorar, ademas hay una [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/456882/183782) del mismo tema

Comment: lo siento por demorarme, ya esta la respuesta

Comment: lo que pasa es que cada funcion hace una cosa y una no tiene que ver con la otra, lo primero que tienes que hacer es llamar a la funcion que te clasifique y el resultado de esa, se lo pasas a la otra que te calcula el numero de bandejas

Comment: si pero nose como unirlo todo

Comment: te puedo dar la respuesta, pero como dije en mi respuesta, la cosa es que entiendas la lógica de como funciona, trata de hacer algo mas busca como puedes hacer lo que quieres, como sugerencia implementa mi código, pues es mas sencillo y abreviado

Comment: lo que pasa es que tu Código me da un error y no da la respuesta esperada, y llevo 7 dias intentando resolver esto y no he podido, tengo que entregarlo a media noche

Comment: Yo solo simplifiqué tu código, si no funciona es por que tu código tampoco lo hace, en un momento edito la respuesta, la explicación no será muy extensa, pues yo también estoy ocupado.

Comment: esta bien Gracias

Comment: listo, respuesta editada, ahora me voy a hacer mi tarea

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo estas aprendiendo a programas, por lo que me tomaré el tiempo de explicarte todo lo que pasa en el proceso para llegar al resultado.

Primero sabemos que como entrada tenemos una lista con varios diccionario, simplificando, tenemos esto `[{'tipo_huevos': 'A', 'numero_huevos': 250}]`, para acceder a un elemento del diccionario lo hacemos con su índice `0`,`1`, etc. veamos un ejemplo.

```py
lista = ["elemento1","2","huevo3",4]

#accedemos al elemento 2
print(lista[1])

#salida-> '2'
```

Bien ahora trabajemos con el dato que tenemos

```py
huevos = [{'tipo_huevos': 'A', 'numero_huevos': 250}]

#en este caso solo hay un elemento, accedemos a su primera posicion (0)
primer_huevo = huevos[0]
print(primer_huevo)
```

**salida**

```
{
  'tipo_huevos': 'A', 
  'numero_huevos': 250
}
```

El resultado de acceder a la primera posición es eso, pues como dijimos al principio, es una lista que contiene diccionarios, este será el resultado si tratamos de acceder a un elemento de una lista que contiene diccionarios (como nuestro ejemplo). Bien, una vez teniendo el diccionario podemos acceder a sus valores de la forma `dict[key]` lo que nos devolverá su `value`, seguimos con nuestro ejemplo

```py
print(primer_huevo)

#recordemos que antes accedimos a la primera posicion con huevos[0]
tipo = primer_huevo["tipo_huevos"]

#es lo mismo que
#huevos[0]["tipo_huevos"]

print(tipo)
```

**salida**

```
'A'
```

Al acceder al diccionario mediante su `key` nos retorna su `value` que en este caso es `A`
Teniendo esto ya podemos escribir un poco del código

```py
def calcular_bandejas(bandejas):
    
    total_bandejas = {} #aqui se almacenara el resultado final
    for i in range(len(bandejas)): #recorremos segun el tamaño de la lista
        tipo = bandejas[i]["tipo_huevos"] #obtenemos el tipo de huevo
        num_huevos = bandejas[i]["numero_huevos"] #obtenemos el numero de huevps
```

Como sabemos que vamos a recibir una lista con `n` elementos hacemos uso de un ciclo `for` y recorremos según los elementos que tenga la lista con `range(len(bandejas))` esto también nos sirve para indicar el índice del elemento al que vamos a  acceder, igual como lo hicimos antes, con `huevos[0]` pero esta vez lo hacemos variable.

Con eso ya tenemos el tipo de huevo y el numero de huevos, que nos falta?, pues realizar la división según el tipo, lo podemos hacer de 2 formas.

**Forma *normal***
Para esta forma haremos la división de bandejas según el tipo de huevo que sea mediante unas sentencias `if/elif/else`

```py
def calcular_bandejas(bandejas):

    for i in range(len(bandejas)):
        ... #codigo anterior
 
        if tipo == "A":
            num_bandejas = num_huevos/30
        elif tipo == "AA":
            num_bandejas = num_huevos/24
        elif tipo == "AAA":
            num_bandejas = num_huevos/12
        elif tipo == "B":
            num_bandejas = num_huevos/30
        elif tipo == "C":
            num_bandejas = num_huevos/50

        print(num_bandejas)
```

**Forma *compleja* pero sencilla**

para esta forma lo único que tenemos que hacer es definir un diccionario que contega los tipo de huevo cuya estructura será `{tipo: funcion}` y te estarás preguntando, ¿Cómo que *funcion*? y resulta que podemos definir como valor una funcion, mas específicamente una `lambda`, estas `lambda` son funciones anónimas que sirven para hacer operaciones sencillas y concretas, en este caso solo dividir.

**sintaxis de una `lambda`**

```
lambda parametros: expresion
```

Ahora vamos con el código.

```py
def calcular_bandejas(bandejas):
    #lo colocamos antes que todo
    tipos = {"A": lambda x: x/30, "AA": lambda x:x/24, "AAA": lambda x:x/12, "B":lambda x:x/30, "C":lambda x:x/50}
    
    for i in range(len(bandejas)):
        ... #codigo anterior
    
        #recordamos que para acceder al valor lo hacemos mediante su key o clave
        #tipo es la clave y usamos los parentesis por que es una funcion
        num_bandejas = tipos[tipo](num_huevos) #le pasamos como argumento el num de huevos
```

Lo que hace la expresión `lambda x: x/30` es que va a recibir como parámetro una variable `x` y esa variable `x` la divide entre `30` y retorna el resultado y así para cada caso, y accedemos a esta función mediante su `key` o `clave` que sera `A`, `AA`, `AAA`, etc.

finalmente solo nos queda retornar un diccionario como resultado

```py
def calcular_bandejas(bandejas):

    total_bandejas = {}
    for i in range(len(bandejas)):
        ... #codigo anterior
        ... #cualquiera de las 2 formas

        #añadimos al diccionario
        total_bandejas[tipo] = {"numero_huevos":num_huevos,"numero_bandejas":math.ceil(num_bandejas)}
    return total_bandejas
```

**probamos con los siguientes datos**

```
#Datos de los huevos

data_huevos = [{'tipo_huevos': 'A', 'numero_huevos': 250},
{'tipo_huevos': 'AAA', 'numero_huevos': 289}, 
{'tipo_huevos': 'B', 'numero_huevos': 344}, 
{'tipo_huevos': 'C', 'numero_huevos': 691}])

#probamos funcion
print(calcular_bandejas(data_huevos ))
```

**salida**

```
{
  'A': {'numero_huevos': 250, 'numero_bandejas': 9}, 
  'AAA': {'numero_huevos': 289, 'numero_bandejas': 25}, 
  'B': {'numero_huevos': 344, 'numero_bandejas': 12}, 
  'C': {'numero_huevos': 691, 'numero_bandejas': 14}
}
```

Decidí explicar todo por que note que no tenias muy claro como hacer tu función y aun te falta mejorar mucho tu lógica y aprender bien las funciones que tiene Python, espero que hayas entendido todo el proceso y que no te pierdas si es que quieres cambiar algo.

**Mejorando la otra función**
Para mejorar la función `clasificacion_huevos()` vamos a hacer un simple `return` si el parámetro devuelve un valor *falsy* de lo contrario hacemos la calsificaion necesario, para eso creamos un diccionario donde se iran sumando la cantidad huevos según su tipo, al final retornamos un diccionario con todos los valores.

```py
def clasificacion_huevos(huevos):
    cant_huevos = {"A":0,"AA":0,"AAA":0,"B":0,"C":0}
    if not huevos:
        return [{'tipo_huevos': 'A', 'numero_huevos': 0},{'tipo_huevos': 'AA', 'numero_huevos': 0}, {'tipo_huevos': 'AAA', 'numero_huevos': 0},{'tipo_huevos': 'B', 'numero_huevos': 0, 'numero_bandejas': 0},{'tipo_huevos': 'C', 'numero_huevos': 0, 'numero_bandejas': 0}]

    for i in range(len(huevos)):
        try:
            tipo_huevo = huevos[i]["tipo_huevos"]
            # print(tipo_huevo)
            cant_huevos[tipo_huevo]+=huevos[i]["numero_huevos"]
        except:
            return "ingrese correctamente los datos"

    return [{'tipo_huevos': 'A', 'numero_huevos': cant_huevos["A"]},{'tipo_huevos': 'AA', 'numero_huevos': cant_huevos["AA"]},{'tipo_huevos': 'AAA', 'numero_huevos': cant_huevos["AAA"]},{'tipo_huevos': 'B', 'numero_huevos': cant_huevos["B"]},{'tipo_huevos': 'C', 'numero_huevos': cant_huevos["C"]}]
```

**probamos**

```
clasificacion = clasificacion_huevos([{'tipo_huevos': 'A', 'numero_huevos': 250},
{'tipo_huevos': 'AAA', 'numero_huevos': 289}, 
{'tipo_huevos': 'B', 'numero_huevos': 344}, 
{'tipo_huevos': 'C', 'numero_huevos': 691}])

print(clasificacion)
```

**resultado**
El resultado es el mismo, pues ningún dato se repite, en caso se repita el resultado cambiará.

```
[{'numero_huevos': 250, 'tipo_huevos': 'A'},
 {'numero_huevos': 0, 'tipo_huevos': 'AA'},
 {'numero_huevos': 289, 'tipo_huevos': 'AAA'},
 {'numero_huevos': 344, 'tipo_huevos': 'B'},
 {'numero_huevos': 691, 'tipo_huevos': 'C'}]
```

Ahora la variable `clasificacion` la pondremos como parámetro de la función `calcular_bandejas` la cual esta de esta manera.

**función `calcular_bandejas()`**

```py
def calcular_bandejas(bandejas):
    total_bandejas = {} #aqui se almacenara el resultado final

    tipos = {"A": lambda x: x/30, "AA": lambda x:x/24, "AAA": lambda x:x/12, "B":lambda x:x/30, "C":lambda x:x/50}

    for i in range(len(bandejas)): #recorremos segun el tamaño de la lista
        tipo = bandejas[i]["tipo_huevos"] #obtenemos el tipo de huevo
        num_huevos = bandejas[i]["numero_huevos"] #obtenemos el numero de huevps

        #recordamos que para acceder al valor lo hacemos mediante su key o clave
        #tipo es la clave y usamos los parentesis por que es una funcion
        num_bandejas = tipos[tipo](num_huevos) #le pasamos como argumento el num de huevos

        total_bandejas[tipo] = {"numero_huevos":num_huevos,"numero_bandejas":math.ceil(num_bandejas)}
    return total_bandejas
```

**probamos**

```
resultado = calcular_bandejas(clasificacion)
print(resultado)
```

**resultado**

```
{'A': {'numero_bandejas': 9, 'numero_huevos': 250},
 'AA': {'numero_bandejas': 0, 'numero_huevos': 0},
 'AAA': {'numero_bandejas': 25, 'numero_huevos': 289},
 'B': {'numero_bandejas': 12, 'numero_huevos': 344},
 'C': {'numero_bandejas': 14, 'numero_huevos': 691}}
```

DE NADA!

Comment: Gracias Christian , ¿Qué me recomiendas para mejorar mi lógica de programación? cualquier recurso seria de ayuda

Comment: Christian disculpa el codigo me da error cuando intento calcular: 8.333333333333334
14.75
24.083333333333332
11.466666666666667
13.82
{'C': {'numero_huevos': 691, 'numero_bandejas': 14}}

Comment: cual es el error que te da? y que le estas pasando como argumento?

Comment: hola Christian lo que pasa es que me equivoque al poner lo de calcular_bandejas ya que en la salida si yo no le doy argumentos no debe salir nada

Comment: voy a adjuntar una imagen de la salida